# Regression analysis of a correlation coefficient

Tags: regression, correlation, econometrics, least-squares, nonlinear-regression

I have a time series of the 250 day historical correlation and I need to determine what causes this correlation to change as different explanatory variables change. Is there a way that I can regress the correlation coefficient on my explanatory variables? I know standard OLS won't work as the Y variable (correlation) is bounded between -1 and 1.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work? Have you tried? What do you get?

Comment: When using out of sample X variables that are much larger the results are larger than 1 so I need a way to limit the model so that max Y = 1

Comment: I see your issue after reading this [post](http://www.theanalysisfactor.com/proportions-as-dependent-variable-in-regression-which-type-of-model/) - different issue, but related.